# How to use basedir and workingDirectory parameters for scm:checkin goal in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-scm

I'm very new to Maven, and I'm confused about the purpose and correct usage of the `basedir` and `workingDirectory` parameters of the Maven SCM Plugin. Let's say I have the following file/folder structure (in Windows):

```
C:\fruits\
├───.git\
├───apples\
│   └───pom.xml
└───oranges\
    └───pom.xml
```

Before executing Maven (by invoking `mvn.cmd` from the command line), I change the *current directory* in shell to "`C:\fruits\apples`". Thus, in Maven's terms, "`C:\fruits\apples`" becomes the *working directory* with the appropriate `pom.xml` file to use for the `apples` project. On the other hand, in Git's terms, the *working directory* is "`C:\fruits`", because that's where the whole monorepo branch is checked out.

At some point during the build process, I use the Maven SCM Plugin to push some modifications. Currently, when specifying the `scm:checkin` goal, I provide `--define workingDirectory="C:\fruits"`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct path here. Also, the plugin seems to work even though I currently don't define the `basedir` parameter at all, which is surprising, because the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html) lists `basedir` as the only **required** parameter. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't explain the purpose of the `basedir` parameter (they just say it's "the base directory", duh), and doesn't explain which "working directory" (i.e., whether in Git's sense or in Maven's sense) the `workingDirectory` parameter is supposed to point at.

Could you please explain to me, exactly what paths should I define the `basedir` and `workingDirectory` parameters of the SCM plugin to point at (while Maven is working on my `apples` project) and why?

Comment: Please show your pom file because I don't understand why you need scm plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`working directory` parameter for SCM Plugin is in the context of Git i.e. the location of .git folder

`basedir` is the directory for the location of pom.xml. Maven has many default properties and one of them is `basedir`.

To find out more on how it is implemented, you can also check the code for this plugin from maven central or check ur local maven repo.

Comment: Ah, so that's why I didn't need to explicitly provide the `basedir` parameter using `--define`: because it was already predefined by Maven?